# Calculating number of tokens in c statements

Tags: c

The number of tokens in the following C statement.

```
print("℅d",a+=b);
```

Can any one tell me whether `+=` operator should be considered as one token or two tokens

Answer (score 5):

According to the C11 standard, [§6.4.6 Punctuators](http://port70.net/~nsz/c/c11/n1570.html#6.4.6), the 'punctuators' in C are:

```
[ ] ( ) { } . ->
++ -- & * + - ~ !
/ % << >> < > <= >= == != ^ | && ||
? : ; ...
= *= /= %= += -= <<= >>= &= ^= |=
, # ##
<: :> <% %> %: %:%:
```

As you can see, `+=` is one of the punctuators — it's a single token.

Therefore, there are 9 tokens in your statement:

> ```
> print("℅d",a+=b);
> ```

1. `print`
2. `(`
3. `"%d"`
4. `,`
5. `a`
6. `+=`
7. `b`
8. `)`
9. `;`

Answer (score -2):

In a C source program, the basic element recognized by the compiler is the "token." A token is source-program text that the compiler does not break down into component elements.

Basically, `+=` is a shorthand operator; the compiler treats it as a single token.

**For Ex:**

```
x+=10;
x = x + 10;
```

Both the above codes are same, in the first line of code, the compiler will treat `+=` as one token, whereas in the second it will treat `=` and `+` as two tokens.

See Microsoft docs for more information about [C tokens](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/c-language/c-tokens).

Comment: No; that is wrong.  `+=` is a single token.  So is `>>=`.

Comment: So I see.  I'm not sure about the meaning of "compiler breaks it as one token only".  I think I'd be happier if you said something like _Even though `+=` is a shorthand operator, the compiler treats it as a single token._  Also, be aware that in a context such as `data[i++]->member += 10;` the result is not the same as `data[i++]->member = data[i++]->member + 10;`.  At minimum, the `+=` version is defined behaviour and the expanded version is not.